# What are the characteristics of fluorescence microscope that allow detection of living cells?

Tags: optics

How can we see living cells underneath it?

Comment: Are you asking how a microscope works?  Or are you asking why it works for living cells? (Then you should say why you think it shouldn't, and I think you should better ask the biologists that)

Comment: @ACuriousMind Actually, a fluorescence microscope operates differently than a regular microscope. But yes, the OP should improve his question to limit the answers.